# Angular Unshift error when submit data to mongodb

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, mean-stack

When I submit data to MongoDB angular unshift keyword gives this error. I don't know much about Angular. Why does it give me this error?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'unshift' of undefined
```

Here is my code which gives this error:

```
var app=angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('PostsCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('/api/posts')
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.posts = response.post;

        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    });



$scope.addPost=function(){
    if($scope.postBody){
    $http.post('/api/posts',{
        username:'Tahir',
        body:$scope.postBody
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
           $scope.posts.unshift(post)
           $scope.postBody=null

           alert(JSON.stringify(response));
          }, function errorCallback(response) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
        })


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you got this error for this code `$scope.posts.unshift(post)` because of `$scope.posts` is `undefined` so you have to check  `$scope.posts`  is `undefined` or not or you should define first like `$scope.posts = []`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got this error for this code `$scope.posts.unshift(post)` because of `$scope.posts` is `undefined` so you should define first `$scope.posts`.

can try this one

```
var app=angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('PostsCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.posts = [];
    $http.get('/api/posts')
    .then(function(response) {
        // if response.post is single post then should push on posts
        // $scope.posts.push(response.post);
        // if got array then 
        $scope.posts = response.post ? response.post : [];

        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    });



$scope.addPost=function(){
    if($scope.postBody){
    $http.post('/api/posts',{
        username:'Tahir',
        body:$scope.postBody
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
           $scope.posts.unshift(post)
           $scope.postBody=null
          }, function errorCallback(response) {
        })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$scope.posts` is undefined.
You can solve it like this

```
$scope.posts = $scope.posts || [];
$scope.posts.unshift(post);
```

the first line checks assign empty array if the `posts` is null

Comment: Thanks for your Help Sir You are Great :)